# Do we have inequality for this nested $\inf$ expression?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a unital  Banach algebra. I am trying to work out whether

$$ 
\left | \inf_{\|c\|=1} \|ac\| - \inf_{\|d\|=1}\|bd\| \right | \stackrel{\ast}{=}
\inf_{\|c\|=1} \inf_{\|d\|=1} \left |  \|ac\| - \|bd\|\right | 
\stackrel{\ast \ast}{=} \inf_{\|d\|=1}\inf_{\|c\|=1} \left |\|ac\|-\|bd\| \right |$$

My first guess was that no, it obviously can't be true, it has to be $\stackrel{\ast}{\ge}$ because making each term in the difference small separately is bound to be bigger than making the entire difference expression  $ \|ac\| - \|bd\|$ small. But then it occurred to me that $\inf_{\|c\|=1} \inf_{\|d\|=1}$ does not make the entire expression small at once but rather each term in it separately. So it seems to be no different from the first expression. And now I don't know what to think anymore. I suspect though that $\ast \ast$ is indeed an equality. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality (*) is not  true:
Consider $2\times 2$ real matrices with the $2$-norm. Set 
$$
a= I_2, \ b = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$, and
$$
\inf_{c: \|c\|=1} \|ac\|=1, \ \inf_{c: \|c\|=1} \|bc\|=0.
$$
To see the latter choose $c = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
On the other hand,
$$
\inf_{c:\|c\|=1}\inf_{d:\|d\|=1} \big| \|ac\|-\|bd\|\big| = \inf_{d:\|d\|=1} \big| 1-\|bd\|\big| = 0
$$
by choosing $b=d$. Hence
$$
\left|\inf_{c: \|c\|=1} \|ac\| - \inf_{c: \|c\|=1} \|bc\|\right| = 1 > \inf_{c:\|c\|=1}\inf_{d:\|d\|=1} \big| \|ac\|-\|bd\|\big| =0.
$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you happen to have any idea whether $\ge$ or $\le$ holds?